# How to sort a dataframe with rangeindex [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just started to learn python for data processing. Sorry if this is too basic, but I really couldn't find a solution. I created a DataFrame from a list of tuples:

```
A=[(0, 1, 0.0),
   (88, 2, 8.3),
   (89, 2, 5.5),
   (96, 2, 7)]
df = pd.DataFrame(A)
```

Now I got a dataframe with RangeIndex. How could I sort the data by one column? I found a lot of tutorial and examples, e.g., `df.sort_values(by=['col'])`, this works with named indexes or columns. But since the df doesn't have a name, how do I specify it in the sort_values method? Or how do I sort the dataframe by the third column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly as you did, and `sort_values` worked fine for me. In fact, I didn't have a RangeIndex; just a normal pandas dataframe. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
x = [(6,5,4), (3,2,1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
print(df) # View the unsorted dataframe
df.sort_values(by=0) # Sorts by the 0th column
print(df) # View the sorted dataframe
```

Even though my columns aren't named, they are still indexed, so I can refer to them by their number when sorting.

Comment: you are right. what if I want to filter the records on the second column value larger than 2?

Comment: `df.filter('>2')`. For simple, straightforward questions like these, I would direct you to the pandas documentation on filtering (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).

Comment: Perhaps `df = df.filter('>2')`? Try tinkering around with it. You'll also need to specify which column you're filtering on (documentation is your friend!)

Comment: `df.filter('>2')` column number is not in the code. Don't think it will work anyways.  tried `df.filter(1>2)` also doesn't work. Maybe I'm not familiar with the documentation, but still hard to find answers when the questions are not exact in the documentation.